# Deserialization through jackson fails with parent/child classes

Tags: java, json, jackson

There is an abstract class `Product` and another class `SomeProduct` which extends `Product`.

`Product`:

```
@JsonTypeInfo
(
use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes
({
   @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SomeProduct.class, name = Product.PRODUCT_TYPE_SOME)
})
public abstract class Product
{
    static final String PRODUCT_TYPE_SOME = "some_product";
}
```

`SomeProduct`:

```
public class SomeProduct extends Product
{
    @JsonProperty("status")
    @JsonSerialize(include =  JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT)
    private int status;

    public int getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

There will be more classes (different products) which will extend `Product`.

When I serialize it using `ObjectMapper`,

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Product p = new SomeProduct();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(p);
```

this is the output:

> {"type":"some_product"}

Now, when I try to deserialize it back,

```
Product x = mapper.convertValue(json, Product.class);
```

this exception is thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected token (VALUE_STRING), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property 'type' that is to contain type id  (for class com.shubham.model.Product)
>    at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]

What am I doing wrong here ? I've looked on SO and found a question where `defaultImpl` was used in `JsonTypeInfo`. But I can't deserialize the json back to a "Default Impl" since the JSON will always be valid for a specific implementation.

Using Jackson 2.4.3

Comment: Could this be the issue? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14228184/4793951

Comment: @Zircon As mentioned in the code snippet, I've only specified "JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME". Also, "JsonTypeInfo" is set only on the base class, and not in the subclasses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrongly using `mapper.convertValue(json, Product.class);`. You should use:
`mapper.readValue(json, Product.class);`

convertValue use:

> Convenience method for doing two-step conversion from given value, into
>         instance of given value type, if (but only if!) conversion is needed.
>         If given value is already of requested type, value is returned as is.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the problem.