# Nested polymorphic deserialization with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization

I have a use case very similar to [Jackson deserializing nested polymorphic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222429/jackson-deserializing-nested-polymorphic-type) , except that I want to have two nested abstract types deserialized based on `JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY` with different property names.

Supertype:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "first_level_discriminant")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SecondLevel.class, name = "second_level")
})
public abstract class FirstLevel { }
```

Second-level type:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "second_level_discriminant")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConcreteType.class, name = "concrete_type")
})
public abstract class SecondLevel { }
```

Concrete type:

```
public class ConcreteType extends SecondLevel {
    public String value;
}
```

But when I try to deserialize `{"first_level_discriminant":"second_level","second_level_discriminant":"concrete_type","value":"value"}`, I get a regular abstract type error (`Can not construct instance of SecondLevel: abstract types either need...`). Deserializing `SecondLevel` directly works, and so does deserializing concrete subtypes of `FirstLevel`. There is a "checked" answer on the mentioned question, but as far as I understand, it suggests flattening the class hierarchy to single polymorphic type.